# Linq Join to List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list as follows:

```
    List<int> loc = new List<int>();
```

which I populate.

Note that the list stores int values.

I like to join this list to a db table as follow.

What I need to do is something like:

```
    var result = (from pc in db.loc_details
                  join l in loc
                  on pc.locid = loc
                  select pc).ToList();
```

I get an error obviously: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Connection.Generics.List to 'int'.

What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `on pc.locid = l`?  (Just making a logical guess, I almost never use that syntax for LINQ and personally prefer the extension methods directly.)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to join a single `int` to the *entire list*.

Try

```
var result = (from pc in db.loc_details
              join l in loc
              on pc.locid equals l
              select pc).ToList();
```

although that will gve you a *different* error if you are using EF since it can't translate a join to an in-memory list to SQL.  If that is the case, you can use `Contains` which gets translated to an `IN` clause:

```
var result = (from pc in db.loc_details
                  where loc.Contains(pc.locid)
                  select pc).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks will give that a try.

Comment: I don't think this will compile? join statements require the use of the `equals` keyword, rather than `=`

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
List<int> loc = new List<int>();
var result = (from pc in db.loc_details
              join l in loc
              on pc.locid = loc
              select pc);
```

Answer yourself: what is the type of `pc.LocId`? And what is the type of `loc`?
Now look at your code:

```
on pc.locid = loc
```

by the way, shouldn't the `=` be `equals` or at least `==`?